# How to use HC-05 to recieve data?

Tags: led, bluetooth, hc-05

I am trying to control an led with a bluetooth module, but it is not working with an if else condition.

When I use this code I found on the internet the led blinks when I send the string from an android app:

```
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
     pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // put your setup code here, to run once:
     }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
     if(Serial.available()>0)
       {     
          char data= Serial.read(); // reading the data received from the bluetooth module
          switch(data)
          {
            case 'a': digitalWrite(13, HIGH);break; // when a is pressed on the app on your smart phone
            case 'd': digitalWrite(13, LOW);break; // when d is pressed on the app on your smart phone
            default : break;
          }
          Serial.println(data);
       }
       delay(50);
    }
```

Where as when I use this code that I made myself the code compiles and uploads but the serial does not recieve values and the led does not change state when the strings are sent from the app, can someone help me identify why?:

```
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
     pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
     }

    void loop() {
     if(Serial.available()>0)
       {     
          char data= Serial.read();
          if (data == 'a')
          {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
          }
          else if (data == 'b')
          {
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
          }
          Serial.println(data);
       }
       delay(50);
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: are you certain that something does not print ..... it may be a space or tab or carriage return or newline ....... print the ascii value of `data`

Comment: @jsotola Yes, I am certain nothing prints when I use the if else conditon, but the led on the HC-05 blinks just as I send the data, so I am sure the connection is not at fault.